# Using grep with execl ,it starts an infinite loop?

Tags: c, ubuntu, os.execl

I'm doing a small c program for testing some Unix commands. 
I provide the user with choices he can test and then allows him to enter his choice. If the user enters the number 2 as his choice ,the following code should run which is testing the grep command on a file. But there is something wrong with the code
when I enter the "pattern", it starts an infinite loop , 
Any help ?!!  I don't have much experience in Unix progamming.
the problem appears when I enter the number 2 as my choice ,means that it's in case no.2

```
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <sys/wait.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){
    char pattern[50];
    int userInput;
    pid_t childPID; 
        char filename[50];   
    FILE *file;      

    printf("Enter a File name:");    
    scanf("%s",filename);    

        file = fopen(filename, "r");


do{
    printf("Enter what u want to do with the file:\n");
    printf("1.Compress the file.\n");
    printf("2.Search for a pattern at the file\n");
    printf("3.Read the file (display the file content at the terminal)\n");
    printf("4.Eject the program\n");

        scanf("%d",&userInput);
switch(userInput){
    case 1: 
        if(childPID == 0){
            execl("/bin/gzip","gzip",filename,NULL);

            exit(1);
            }       
        break;
    case 2: childPID = fork();
        if(childPID ==0){
            printf("Enter the pattern you want to search about:");
            scanf("%s",pattern);


            execl("/bin/grep","grep",pattern,filename,NULL);
        }   
        break;

    }

}while(userInput != 4);
return 0;
  }
```

Comment: How is pattern defined? Is it large enough to hold your example pattern string?

Comment: I think you should use option `-f` .. means pass 4th argument as     `"-f"` and then `filename`

Comment: @OlafDietsche ,thi is how I defined the pattern

 char pattern[50];

Comment: @Omkant 
I tried that but when i compile ,it produces me this error:


    Ass.c: In function ‘main’:
Ass.c:45:39: error: ‘f’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Ass.c:45:39: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: How do you know it's an infinite loop? What happens exactly?

Comment: use as string not as variable.. write `execl(...,...,"-f",...,...);`

Comment: @OlafDietsche ,I'm actually using a do while loop to repeat the choices provided to the user every time unless he enters the number 4 and the switch cases are inside the loop.
After I enter the pattern it starts repeating the choices and never stops

Comment: @Omkant same problem appears, it starts an infinite loop :(

Comment: @OlafDietsche I will edit my code to contain the loop I'm using

Comment: in case 1 you haven't called `fork()` and comparing the childPid value which will be indeterminate

Comment: @Omkant , it's not the problem! still executing the same way

Comment: @GhadeerWalid :See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execlp()` or `exec()` family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image so when `execlp()` exits then child terminates but `fork()` returns some non-zero value to parent process.

The main point is after doing `fork()` there are two independent processes

```
1st : main process called parent 
2nd : child process
```

And you can't control their execution order it's unspecified. so put `wait(NULL)` in you parent code just after the child code finishes.

So that parent will wait till child terminates. otherwise both independent processes will run in this way. Sometimes you find that only parent is running `(that's infinite loop)` but sometimes you see that child is running too.

Comment: That's right, it worked and stopped the infinite loop, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I see this could get into an infinite loop is when `execl()` fails. Print errno after `execl()` to see what's going wrong.

```
...
    execl("/bin/grep","grep",pattern,filename,NULL);
    printf("errno=%d\n", errno);
}

break;
```

Comment: I can't stop executing the program to know what is the error ?!